# how to perform url rewriting using HTACCESS in server

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have the following **.htaccess** file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteRule   ^index/?$   index1.php  [NC]
RewriteRule   ^index/(.*\.html)/?$   index1.php?load=$1  [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^page/?$   page.php  [NC]
RewriteRule  ^page/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)/([{a-z}{0-9}{\-\}]+)/?$   page.php?id=$1&cat=$2&title=$3 [NC,L]
```

and its work perfectly in my localhost. but not works in server,

the following **.htaccess** works good in my server

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule testpage\.html http://www.google.com [R]
```

did i make any mistake? any help?